# C89 - Block of code in for loop increment clause

Tags: c, for-loop, grammar, c89

Is it possible, according to the C89/C90 standard, to insert a block of code into the increment clause of a for statement?

For instance:

```
int x = 0, y;
for (y = 0; x + y < SOME_CONST; { y++; x++; })
{
    //code
}
```

instead of:

```
int x = 0, y;
for (y = 0; x + y < SOME_CONST; x++)
{
    y++;
    //code
}
```

All I know so far is that it won't work with the Microsoft C/C++ compiler, but what does the standard say?

And what about the initialization clause? Can I put a block of code in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grammar for the `for` *iteration-statement* in C89 is

`for` `(`*expression<sub>opt</sub>*`;` *expression<sub>opt</sub>*`;` *expression<sub>opt</sub>*`)` *statement*

Where *expression<sub>opt</sub>* is either an *expression* or omitted: e.g. `for (;;);` is valid `C`. Simply put, `{y++; x++;}` is **not** an *expression<sub>opt</sub>* but rather it's a *statement*. So it can't be used in the `for` loop. Something like `x++, y++` is an *expression* with a value of the previous value of `y` so it can be.

In later versions of C, the first *expression<sub>opt</sub>* is enhanced to a *clause* which permits code like `for (int a...`. But this is **not** valid in C89. But code like `for (x = 1, y = 2;` **is** valid since `x = 1, y = 2` is an *expression*.

Comment: So I could initialize also as
    for(x = y = 0 ...
?

Comment: @NahuelPrieto indeed you can: `x = y = 0` is an *expressionopt* with a value of `0`.

Comment: I don't think there's anything called an "expressionopt". The grammar you're reading is probably a bad OCR or pdftotext conversion of a source that said "expression" with "opt" as a subscript indicating that it's optional. I blame the standards people for still using dead tree formats in the 21st century...

Answer (score 3):

You can't do a "block" of code, but you can have comma separated statements. For example,

```
int x = 0, y;
for (y = 0; x + y < SOME_CONST; y++, x++ )
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: Wow, very interesting, and is that syntax exclusive to a for loop or is it inherited from somewhere else?

Comment: You can have commas between things in any expression.

Comment: And for consistency: `for (x = y = 0; x + y < SOME_CONST; x++, y++)` works neatly too; you could also write `for (x = 0, y = 0; …)`.